# Distribute multi-compiler and multi-platform library (C++)

Tags: c++, cross-platform, software-distribution

Is it possible to distribute a library that will work for any compiler the user wants to build/link with? (assuming it understands c++ standard). If so, could it `.dlls`/`.so` or would it have to be a header-only library?

Basically I'd like my library to be easily usable to people on windows using Visual Studio and people on linux using gcc, and other platforms too.

Comment: _"Is it possible to distribute a library that will work for any compiler the user wants to build/link with? "_ No, that's not possible.

Comment: There is no way to have one library that supports x86, x64, ARM, ... all at the same time, sorry.

Comment: @Rakete Apple has libraries that support all of those. Sure, it's a format that just puts all three in one, but still possible.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Wait, really? I thought that wasn't possible :) Now I'm wondering why Apple is the only one doing it...

Comment: Is this intended to be without any developer side configuration? If you're willing to put up with a bit of "Run this to configure library for your target and development system" I'd say you've described Boost.